# adding QProgress bar within QLineEdit in PyQt or PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, custom-controls, qlineedit, qprogressbar

Hi I want to add the QProgressBar behind the QLIneEdit, just like it is in Safari Browser or IE, So here is my starting point how can I hook the ProgressBar and MyLineEdit together so that when user is done entering the path the progress bar should show the progress while the path is opened !!!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class ProgressBar(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    """ docstring for ProgressBar
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.step = 0
        self.doAction()

    def timerEvent(self, e):

        if self.step >= 100:

            self.timer.stop()
            return

        self.step = self.step + 15
        self.setValue(self.step)

    def doAction(self):

        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.timer.start(100, self)




class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    """ docstring for MyLineEdit
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        # I want to hook this bar at the backgroind of MyLineEdit
        pbar = ProgressBar()


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pbar = ProgressBar(self)
        self.editbx = MyLineEdit(self.pbar)
        newPalette = QtGui.QPalette()
        newPalette.setColor(self.editbx.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.editbx.setPalette(newPalette)
        self.editbx.setText("Defaukt text set")
        self.editbx.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border:none;}")
        self.pbar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar {border:none;}")

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QProgressBar')
        self.show()



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also looking forward to add a QCombobox in place of text entered so it can list the other existing folders, not the way QCompleter uses though becuase it doesnt has look of QCombobox, and I do not want to allow user to enter anything that doesnt exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question as you posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395619/how-to-place-qcombobox-ontop-of-qprogressbar-in-pyqt I know it doesn't have an answer either, just wanted to check

Comment: aahh yes, actually I forgot about it and since its only now I got time so started something on it, I will delete the old question you pointed.

Answer (score 2):

I've attached an example of a QLineEdit with a progress bar behind it. It was heavily influenced by this post: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54758-Progress-bar-form-QLineEdit-issue

Basically you have to manage painting yourself. Unfortunately it didn't seem to work when I tried to do the same thing with a QComboBox. I would suggest posting a new question specifically about painting a progress bar on a QComboBox once you get up to it!

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timer = QBasicTimer()
        self.step = 0
        self.doAction()

    def timerEvent(self, e):
        if self.step >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            return

        self.step = self.step + 10
        self.repaint()        

    def doAction(self):
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.timer.start(1000, self)

    def generateGradient(self, color):
        gradient = QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, self.height());
        m_defaultBaseColor = self.palette().color(QPalette.Base)
        gradient.setColorAt(0, m_defaultBaseColor)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.15, color.lighter(120))
        gradient.setColorAt(0.5, color)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.85, color.lighter(120))
        gradient.setColorAt(1, m_defaultBaseColor)
        return gradient

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        p = QPainter(self)
        panel = QStyleOptionFrameV2()
        self.initStyleOption(panel)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_PanelLineEdit, panel, p, self)

        # an alternative to painting the QLineEdit is to do it only when the widget has focus and the progress bar is finished
        #if self.hasFocus() or self.step >= 100: QLineEdit.paintEvent(self, event)

        # however I've chosen to paint it always
        QLineEdit.paintEvent(self, event)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        lenap = QStyleOptionFrameV2()
        self.initStyleOption(lenap)
        backgroundRect = self.style().subElementRect(QStyle.SE_LineEditContents, lenap, self)

        # some alternative if statements you might like to use instead...
        #
        # if not self.hasFocus() and self.step < 100:
        # if self.step < 100:
        if True:
            loadingColor = QColor(116,192,250)
            painter.setBrush(self.generateGradient(loadingColor))
            painter.setPen(Qt.transparent)
            mid = int(backgroundRect.width()/100.0*self.step)
            progressRect = QRect(backgroundRect.x(), backgroundRect.y(), mid, backgroundRect.height())
            painter.drawRect(progressRect)

            painter.setPen(Qt.SolidLine)
            painter.drawText(backgroundRect, Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter, " " + self.text())


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self._control = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._control)

        l = QVBoxLayout(self._control)
        e = MyLineEdit()
        l.addWidget(e)
        b = QPushButton('a')
        l.addWidget(b)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: well, I tried at home on OSx and it doesn't seems to work, since I am not able to type in either..

Comment: Hmm, worked in windows (typing as well) though the text cursor didn't show up. You might want to try some of the alternative if statements I included in the code to see if that helps

Comment: yes it works on Linux as well, I think background for text in OSx is not working

Comment: So, I commented `self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_PanelLineEdit, panel, p, self)` and it works on Osx too, also the cursor is not visible because its behind the progress bar gradient which seems why it is not visible...